How does quantum field theory affect the ontological tenability of composite objects?
I've heard that according to philosophers of physics, QFT does not describe particles as fundamental entities, rather, fields are fundamental and "particles" are used to describe excited states of such fields. Metaphysician Peter van Inwagen makes a similar point in his book, Metaphysics (5th Edition):
And some physicists and philosophers of physics hold that current physics implies something very similar: that so-called    particles—electrons and quarks—do not really exist, that talk of the motions and interactions of particles is nothing more than a    conveniently simple way of describing the excited states of quantum fields.
If particles like quarks and electrons are not fundamental entities but merely excited states of quantum fields, does this imply that composite objects, such as organisms, cannot have independent existence? How do these insights from QFT impact traditional metaphysical views of composition and objecthood?

It seems like if one is willing to defend the mereological existence of 'a chair' despite knowing that it's made up of protons, neutrons, and electrons, it's probably not too much of a stretch to extend that to QFT. Particularly if one is willing to defend the mereological existence of 'a wave' despite it being a pattern in the behaviour of a body of water and not some fixed set of water molecules. So I don't necessarily think QFT would convince somebody who otherwise thinks 'chair' exists, and the mereological nihilist is I think pretty happy to say 'okay, electrons don't exist either'

And other physicists and philosophers suggest that quantum fields "do not really exist" and are just a "conveniently simple way of describing" particle interactions. The objective fact is that QFT admits equivalent formulations both in terms of fields and in terms of particles. It gets even better (or worse) in string theory which has multiple equivalent formulations with vastly different " fundamental entities" due to its dualities. For a discussion see Dawid, who suggests that it "destroys the basis for conventional versions of scientific realism".

Quantum field theory has absolutely nothing to say about the ontological tenability of composite objects. It is a mathematical model used to make predictions about, for example, how light interacts with electrically charged objects at the scale length of single atoms.
Note also that the particles in QFT which make up matter  and which represent the excitations of the underlying fields have a real existence; they are not convenient calculational tools except in the special case of virtual particles.
So, is an electron a "real object"? In a previous lifetime I worked in a factory that used a 1.5 million volt electron beam to crosslink polymers. When the beam was on, the electrons screaming out of the beam tube made the air glow blue one foot away from the beam aperture, and when they struck the steel components inside the beam cell, lethal amounts of x-rays were generated. The exiting plastic coming out of the beam cell exuded ozone gas and carried a residual charge that shocked me as I ran the uptake spooler. To me, those electrons were very, very real (they were capable of killing me) and decidedly not a mathematical description of field excitations.

So would you say Van Inwagen, in that quote, has misconstrued what QFT says?

he's full of ignorance.

@JerraT you have to read his quote as a bit artful, rather than taking it ultra-literally. Try to understand what quantum mechanics says is and isn't the case about the things we call "electrons" and then read his quote again. I think a charitable reading of what he's saying is, "the things we call electrons don't exist in the way we usually think of, as distinct classical objects that bounce around like little balls in the world". When we interact with an electron in a way that makes it seem like we've interacted with a little ball, QFT is saying something more subtle has happened than that

@nielsnielsen quantum mechanics doesn't actually say anything philosophical about the reality of emergent things, which is I think kinda what you're getting at. If you read that guy's quote too literally, I can see why you'd come away with that understanding, but qm doesn't say that and I'd maybe suggest that that's not even what the author intended for you to take away from his words.

QM is somewhat beside the fundamental philosophical question. By claiming that particles are not actually ontological primitives and replacing them by excited regions of quantum fields, you still have ontological prrimities. After that, QM does not provide the metaphysical grounding for deciding one's metaontological theory at all of which there are several approaches, each defensible as a theory. One approach some mereologists advocate is simply denying most or all macroworld ontological commitment. This perspective is called mereological nihilism. From WP:

Philosophers in favor of something close to pure mereological nihilism include Peter Unger, Cian Dorr, and Ross Cameron. There are a few philosophers who argue for what could be considered a partial nihilism, or what has been called quasi-nihilism, which is the position that only objects of a certain kind have parts. One such position is organicism: the view that living beings exist, but there are no other objects with parts... Organicist philosophers include Trenton Merricks and Peter van Inwagen. (emphasis mine)

Thus is Inwagen wrong or right is akin to the question, is partial nihilism correct? And of course, there is no simple right or wrong answer, what might be considered a canonical or consenusual response. Whether you reject mereological composition of particles entirely, mostly, occasionally, or never is a question of your metaontological theory, and thus your personal views on ontological commitment. For Quine, for instance, the right answer was ontological relativity.

What a weird exception to carve out. No composite objects exist except living things. "I'm a living thing, and of course I exist, and I'm a composite object.... but no other composite objects are real"

@TKoL That's totally what I thought! :D But I think it follows to head off the question, well if there are no things, how can you, a thing, question whether or not there are things? Thus, it's an ad hoc, oh, well, there are living things, obviously. lol

This answer is complete in itself but it is intended as a follow-up to Niels Nielsen's answer and a reply to the question in the comments.

There are two errors:
"Is excited state of quantum field therefore not-is" is a non-sequitur. The conclusion denies the premise.
Separate from the non-sequitur, the premise (is excited state of quantum field) is false. Excited states of quantum fields are mathematical objects that we use to make predictions about measurements of the real things. Real systems are not the mathematical objects that we use to make predictions about measurements of the real systems. This is a basic category error of the type described in wiki: map-territory relation.
I imagine that if cornered, Van Inwagen would agree that this is just a linguistic blunder and not what he really would have said if he had sufficiently thought through what he wanted to express.

A more correct expression of the (hopefully) intended meaning is:
"Electrons, quarks, etc are part-wise encodings of the measurable properties of posited physical systems."
Note:

Electrons, quarks, etc are part-wise encodings "these terms refer to elements of a map"


of the measurable properties of posited physical systems "the
territory mapped is possible measurements"

Put another way, they are a part-wise encoding of the way to get answers to the question, "If we had measured such and such already, what could we measure later?"
Their mathematical structure points to, but is not the same as, the qualities of the physical reality so encoded, whether you prefer to approach the mathematical structure using the metaphor of tiny invisible rocks or tiny invisible agitations in a big invisible ocean; and that physical reality may not be able to be formally discretized into localized parts with a 1:1 correspondence to parts of the mathematical structure.

Note that this approach does not deny reality; it affirms the underlying reality. The particles are (elements of) the map; the map is the map of measurements, the measurements are measurements of reality.

In my personal opinion, the main insight available from of 20th century physics to the metaphysics of composition and objecthood is to take the map-territory distinction and really beat it into your head as a non-optional practical reality. Particle physics attests that it is not just true that the perception is not the object perceived (see e.g. Kant's noumena/phenomena distinction) but that that truth must be incorporated into your model if you want to make accurate predictions.

"I imagine that if cornered, Van Inwagen would agree that this is just a linguistic blunder and not what he really would have said if he had sufficiently thought through what he wanted to express." - I believe this. He's speaking artfully and with brevity, and wasn't anticipating just how far op would read into his quote.

Yes, QFT has its application in particle physics. As the name already indicates the basic physical concept of QFT is the field, and the particle is a secondary phenomenon as explained in the question.

The most simple compound system in physics is the hygrogen atom. It
links two particles, the proton and the electron. The mechanism of
QFT, more specific quantum electrodynamics (QED), formalizes the
interaction between charged particles and the electromagnetic field
by the mechanism of exchanging photons.
Nevertheless the
classical concept of stable particles like the proton and electron
does not loose its importance for studying the basic case of the
hydrogen atom.

In general, when observing elementary particles on the quantum level
one has to compute the probability densitiy and to study the field
equation. Nevertheless, when observing the particle in an experiment
one always observes one whole particle, never an extended particle
smeard out over the whole area where the probability
of the field is non zero.
Hence, in most cases and notably for every-day
experience there is no need to argue with the underlying fields from QFT.

But for a philosopher of physics it is a challenge to investigate the
new ontology due of the paradigm change from particle to
field.


